# Why is eclipse SVN team menu not showing all options?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm new to eclipse IDE. I've made some changes in the code and want to checkin/commit my changes to svn. But when I right click on a project and choose team option, I don't see options like commit, update, etc. I've searched on internet about the problem and tried following options,

1. unistalling & reinstalling **subversive - svn team provider**
2. starting eclipse with  -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
   but nothing worked for me.

Please see following image for more info.
[image: SVN Team menu not working as expected]

More details about eclipse IDE, which I'm using, are as follows,
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800

I'm on windows 8.1 64 bit machine, if it matters. If anything else is required to solve the error, please let me know.

Comment: Can you show how the `Team` menu looks like after you have shared your project.

Comment: @AleksandrM it is same. :(

Answer (score 12):

You have you run 'Team > Share Project...' to tell SVN that this project is an SVN project before you can do anything else. Once you have set up the sharing the other menu items will appear.

Comment: When I do that it shows follows error, 

Share project was failed.
svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at
'E:\' (format '31').

Any idea, why is this happening?

Comment: Some compatibility problem with the version of SVN in Eclipse and the version that created the working copy.

Comment: Ok.. got it. I'll try to upgrade my project or downgrade svn version and get back to you. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I shared the project and still, it doesn't show all the menus :| BTW, the project is already checked out from SVN and still i don't see the menu. Anything else I've do?

Answer (score 4):

Try to import the original project as an SVN Project (through File>Import...) directly from the repository (use a new project name if you get conflicts). Verify that the Team menu is working for this project.

Comment: tried it, but doesn't work for existing project :| But it worked for new project, which I imported.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with my workspace. Here is the solution

Right-clicking "myproject" and click Team,Then Share Project. It should ask you what type of repository, and when you move to the next screen it should indicate that it sees existing SVN/ directories at which point it should use that metadata to establish the link. It may also require that you have the SVN repository set up (in the SVN Repositories perspective).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create your project from your SVN repository. for that :

```
 File > New > Other > SVN > Repository Location
```

In this windows you'll have all settings to configure your client use of SVN.

Comment: I'm not looking to create new repository. I've checked out projects from svn and now I don't see options like commit, revert on the projects.

Comment: I understood, in this case go to File > New > Other > SVN > "Project from SVN".
But if you have no repository (the one which arleady contain your project) the menus will lead you to my first proposition.
Once you've downloaded all your sources, you can check that the team menu is working.

Comment: Yup, project from SVN worked. But existing projects don't work

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project and select Refactor then select Rename now it will work.